# react hook form clears input field after I enter field name

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form  to validate text input field.

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ mode: 'onBlur' });

<input
  name='name'
  type='text'
  onInput={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
  {...register('name',{ required: true })}
/>
```

My problem is that when I enter text 'name' in that input - text clears.
Also I have another input with name blog.

```
<input
  name='blog'
  type='text'
  onInput={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
  {...register('blog',{ required: true })}
/>
```

Now if I write blog - blog input clears.
Funny thing is that you can write name inside blog input and text in name input clears.
Same way If I write blog inside name input - blog input text clears.

I guess I'm making some dumb mistake, what am I doing wrong ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to specify the name when setting value

```
onInput={(e) => setValue("blog", e.target.value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were going right bro just a tiny mistake in your code.

```
const [blogValue,setBlogValue] = useState("");

<input
  name='blog'
  type='text'
  value ={blogValue}
  onChange={(e) => setBlogValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

I hope your problem is solved. Best of Luck :)